# AMQP 'connection.open' reserved parameters

Tags: erlang, amqp

I am writing an AMQP Client Library in Erlang.  For the 'connection.open' method, there are 2 reserved parameters "documented" in AMQP 0.9.1 out of a total of 3.  When I send the method in question *without* the "reserved parameters", I get "unable to decode method" in the error log.

What should I be sending as value for those "reserved parameters" ??

**Update**:  It seems the server still expects some parameters even if the parameters are deprecated (see source code for [code generator](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-codegen/file/fc46914f99b7/amqp-0.9.1.json)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These used to be "ticket" arguments in previous versions of Amqp, in my own Amqp libs I just send a null for these, you're right that they are required.  It does seem silly to have them in there, hopefully they'll be removed in future versions.